# Two "glossary" elements being generated on my first glossaries page

Tags: formatting, glossaries

I'm successfully generating a glossary, but for whatever reason I'm getting a rogue "Glossary" element before my first glossary entry, but after my Glossary heading.  Here's the relevant example code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,ebook,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\chapterstyle{madsen}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ge1}
{
  name={Entry 1},
  description={My first glossary entry.}
}

\begin{document}
\title{My Fancy Title}
\author{John Smith}
\date{March 2013}
\maketitle
\linespread{1.2}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The House}
It was a dark and stormy night...

\backmatter
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem stems from an incompatibility between `memoir` and `glossaries`. The simplest fix is to move `\pagestyle{ruled}` before `glossaries` is loaded.

```
\documentclass[10pt,ebook,oneside,openright]{memoir}

\pagestyle{ruled}% must be before glossaries is loaded

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\chapterstyle{madsen}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ge1}
{
  name={Entry 1},
  description={My first glossary entry.}
}

\begin{document}
\title{My Fancy Title}
\author{John Smith}
\date{March 2013}
\maketitle
\linespread{1.2}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The House}
It was a dark and stormy night...

\backmatter
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apologies for the dupe, my searches apparently need work.